# how do I include DISTINCT in a multiple join query with SUM

Tags: mysql, join, sum, distinct

The following query gives me ALMOST the correct counts, EXCEPT it is including rows with duplicate p.promo_code and submitid values. How do I get this query to use DISTINCT p.promo_code, submitid?

I have attempted a couple of solutions I saw on SO for single join queries, like  ---   **the sum** * COUNT(DISTINCT p.promo_code, submitid)/count(*)

No Luck. 
Here is the full query:

```
SELECT
          SUM(CASE WHEN ISNULL(p.promo_code) 
                  AND h.account_number = c2.account_number THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as  'no_match_acct_match',
          SUM(CASE WHEN ISNULL(p.promo_code) 
                  AND (h.account_number <> c2.account_number OR ISNULL(c2.account_number)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as  'no_match',
          SUM(CASE WHEN p.promo_code IS NOT NULL 
                  AND c.full_name = CONCAT(h.firstname,' ',h.lastname) 
                  AND p.start_date > @today THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'future_name',
          SUM(CASE WHEN p.promo_code IS NOT NULL 
                  AND c.full_name = CONCAT(h.firstname,' ',h.lastname) 
                  AND p.start_date <= @today 
                  AND p.`status` = 'REDEEMED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'redeemed_name',
          SUM(CASE WHEN p.promo_code IS NOT NULL 
                  AND c.full_name = CONCAT(h.firstname,' ',h.lastname) 
                  AND p.start_date <= @today 
                  AND p.`status` <> 'REDEEMED' 
                  AND p.end_date < @today
                  AND p.end_date + 259200 >= @today THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'buffered_name',
          SUM(CASE WHEN p.promo_code IS NOT NULL 
                  AND c.full_name = CONCAT(h.firstname,' ',h.lastname) 
                  AND p.start_date <= @today 
                  AND p.`status` <> 'REDEEMED' 
                  AND p.end_date < @today
                  AND p.end_date + 259200 < @today THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'expired_name',
          SUM(CASE WHEN p.promo_code IS NOT NULL 
                  AND c.full_name = CONCAT(h.firstname,' ',h.lastname) 
                  AND p.start_date <= @today 
                  AND p.`status` <> 'REDEEMED' 
                  AND p.end_date >= @today THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'current_name',
          SUM(CASE WHEN p.promo_code IS NOT NULL 
                  AND c.full_name <> CONCAT(h.firstname,' ',h.lastname) 
                  AND p.start_date > @today 
                  AND (r.resolve_status = 0 OR ISNULL(r.resolve_status)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'future_noname',
          SUM(CASE WHEN p.promo_code IS NOT NULL 
                  AND c.full_name <> CONCAT(h.firstname,' ',h.lastname) 
                  AND p.start_date <= @today 
                  AND p.`status` = 'REDEEMED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'redeemed_noname',
          SUM(CASE WHEN p.promo_code IS NOT NULL 
                  AND c.full_name <> CONCAT(h.firstname,' ',h.lastname) 
                  AND p.start_date <= @today 
                  AND p.`status` <> 'REDEEMED' 
                  AND p.end_date < @today
                  AND p.end_date + 259200 >= @today THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'buffered_noname',
          SUM(CASE WHEN p.promo_code IS NOT NULL 
                  AND c.full_name <> CONCAT(h.firstname,' ',h.lastname) 
                  AND p.start_date <= @today 
                  AND p.`status` <> 'REDEEMED' 
                  AND p.end_date < @today
                  AND p.end_date + 259200 < @today THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'expired_noname',
          SUM(CASE WHEN p.promo_code IS NOT NULL 
                  AND c.full_name <> CONCAT(h.firstname,' ',h.lastname) 
                  AND p.start_date <= @today 
                  AND p.`status` <> 'REDEEMED' 
                  AND p.end_date >= @today THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'current_noname'
              FROM helpdesk h
              FORCE INDEX (help_status)
              LEFT JOIN promo_codes p
                  ON h.promo_code = p.promo_code
              LEFT JOIN customer_promocode cp
                  ON p.promo_code = cp.promo_code
              LEFT JOIN customers c
                  ON cp.customer_number = c.customer_number
              LEFT JOIN customers c2
                  ON h.account_number = c2.account_number
              LEFT OUTER JOIN redeem_queue r
                  ON p.promo_code = r.promo_code
              WHERE
                  h.help_status = 0
                  AND h.in_view_by = ''
                  AND (p.start_date  >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(SUBDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR))
                  OR p.start_date IS NULL) 
                  AND (ISNULL(p.promo_code) OR ISNULL(r.promo_code))
```

It runs quickly and the explain plan looks good, but because of the duplicate data currently 2 of the counts are off.

Any and all help will be appreciated.

Comment: That's a lot of SQL to digest without data, but have you tried doing a `GROUP BY p.promo_code`? Mind you, since you have `CASE` in your `SUM`, I'm not 100% sure if it's what you're looking for

Comment: Thanks @charmeleon, but using the group by will break the data into a record per promo_code. This query is obtaining the SUM for each of the CASEs.  

I know it is a lot to look at and understand without data. If I don't figure it out soon, or get a solution here, I will post the DDL as well as a small sampling of data from each table.

Answer (score 0):

You should use group by on those columns.

```
SELECT
  SUM(
    CASE WHEN ISNULL(p.promo_code)
    AND h.account_number = c2.account_number THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  ) as 'no_match_acct_match',
  SUM(
    CASE WHEN ISNULL(p.promo_code)
    AND (
      h.account_number <> c2.account_number
      OR ISNULL(c2.account_number)
    ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  ) as 'no_match',
  SUM(
    CASE WHEN p.promo_code IS NOT NULL
    AND c.full_name = CONCAT(h.firstname, ' ', h.lastname)
    AND p.start_date > @today THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  ) as 'future_name',
  SUM(
    CASE WHEN p.promo_code IS NOT NULL
    AND c.full_name = CONCAT(h.firstname, ' ', h.lastname)
    AND p.start_date <= @today
    AND p.`status` = 'REDEEMED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  ) as 'redeemed_name',
  SUM(
    CASE WHEN p.promo_code IS NOT NULL
    AND c.full_name = CONCAT(h.firstname, ' ', h.lastname)
    AND p.start_date <= @today
    AND p.`status` <> 'REDEEMED'
    AND p.end_date < @today
    AND p.end_date + 259200 >= @today THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  ) as 'buffered_name',
  SUM(
    CASE WHEN p.promo_code IS NOT NULL
    AND c.full_name = CONCAT(h.firstname, ' ', h.lastname)
    AND p.start_date <= @today
    AND p.`status` <> 'REDEEMED'
    AND p.end_date < @today
    AND p.end_date + 259200 < @today THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  ) as 'expired_name',
  SUM(
    CASE WHEN p.promo_code IS NOT NULL
    AND c.full_name = CONCAT(h.firstname, ' ', h.lastname)
    AND p.start_date <= @today
    AND p.`status` <> 'REDEEMED'
    AND p.end_date >= @today THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  ) as 'current_name',
  SUM(
    CASE WHEN p.promo_code IS NOT NULL
    AND c.full_name <> CONCAT(h.firstname, ' ', h.lastname)
    AND p.start_date > @today
    AND (
      r.resolve_status = 0
      OR ISNULL(r.resolve_status)
    ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  ) as 'future_noname',
  SUM(
    CASE WHEN p.promo_code IS NOT NULL
    AND c.full_name <> CONCAT(h.firstname, ' ', h.lastname)
    AND p.start_date <= @today
    AND p.`status` = 'REDEEMED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  ) as 'redeemed_noname',
  SUM(
    CASE WHEN p.promo_code IS NOT NULL
    AND c.full_name <> CONCAT(h.firstname, ' ', h.lastname)
    AND p.start_date <= @today
    AND p.`status` <> 'REDEEMED'
    AND p.end_date < @today
    AND p.end_date + 259200 >= @today THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  ) as 'buffered_noname',
  SUM(
    CASE WHEN p.promo_code IS NOT NULL
    AND c.full_name <> CONCAT(h.firstname, ' ', h.lastname)
    AND p.start_date <= @today
    AND p.`status` <> 'REDEEMED'
    AND p.end_date < @today
    AND p.end_date + 259200 < @today THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  ) as 'expired_noname',
  SUM(
    CASE WHEN p.promo_code IS NOT NULL
    AND c.full_name <> CONCAT(h.firstname, ' ', h.lastname)
    AND p.start_date <= @today
    AND p.`status` <> 'REDEEMED'
    AND p.end_date >= @today THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  ) as 'current_noname'
FROM
  helpdesk h FORCE INDEX (help_status)
  LEFT JOIN promo_codes p ON h.promo_code = p.promo_code
  LEFT JOIN customer_promocode cp ON p.promo_code = cp.promo_code
  LEFT JOIN customers c ON cp.customer_number = c.customer_number
  LEFT JOIN customers c2 ON h.account_number = c2.account_number
  LEFT OUTER JOIN redeem_queue r ON p.promo_code = r.promo_code
WHERE
  h.help_status = 0
  AND h.in_view_by = ''
  AND (
    p.start_date >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(SUBDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR))
    OR p.start_date IS NULL
  )
  AND (
    ISNULL(p.promo_code)
    OR ISNULL(r.promo_code)
  )
group by
  p.promo_code,
  submitid
```